# Is there a way to find the object instanceated class name from onther method of that class in Java

Tags: java

I have a requirement to find the object instantiated class name. I searched in web but I didn't find good answer.
The Java application is very old so it is hard to change existing code structure. I want to know at-least it is possible or not. Thanks suggestions are warmly welcome.

```
  public class Test
  {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
      Sub sub = new Sub();
      Thread t = new Thread(){
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
          sub.printInstanceCreatedClassName();
        }
      };
      t.start();
    }
    }
  }

  public class Sub
  {
    public void printInstanceCreatedClassName(){
      // this method should print the instance created class name
      // In this example it should be Test
      System.out.println("Test");
    }
  }
```

by considering all the answers I could find a solution. I add that solution as a answer for this question. Thanks all for the given support.

Comment: this.getClass().getName()

Comment: I don't understand the question. The code example says "In this example it should be Test", but if I understand what you are saying correctly, it actually should be Sub.

Comment: @ShanuGupta this.getClass().getName()  returns the same class name. I want instance created class name

Comment: Do you mean the name of the class that created the instance?

Comment: hmm got it now...

Comment: @RobinGreen actualy want to find the name of instance created one printed name should be Test

Comment: 'Name of instance created one' is meaningless, as is 'object instantiated class name', as is 'instance created class name'. You've been given a number of suggestions as to what you might mean. Please choose one, instead of posting more meaningless variations.

Comment: Well 'caller class name' is yet another thing. Do you mean caller who created the object, or caller who called the method? You can get the latter from the stack trace: no need to write extra code.

Comment: actually I don't want the call the edited person changed it to caller resonantly I saw it now. so I revert it

Comment: Because of that edit question went wrong direction

Comment: Well while you're changing it, why didn't you change it to something that makes sense? You have still not clarified your question despite several requests.

Comment: @EJP because of my poor English question interpreted wrongly. Actually I want the object initialized class form inside of the object. in this case inside the Sub class I want to know Test class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the support given by all of you. By looking at 'Shanu Gupta' answer I could manage my requirement. I don't think this is the best solution but can fulfill my requirement.

Following is the code:

```
  public class Test
  {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
      Sub sub = new Sub();
      Thread t = new Thread(sub::printInstanceCreatedClassName);
      t.start();
    }
  }


  public class Sub
  {
    private String createdClassName;

    public Sub(){
      StackTraceElement[] stackTraceElements = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
      createdClassName =  stackTraceElements[2].getClassName();
    }

    public void printInstanceCreatedClassName(){
      System.out.println(createdClassName);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do something on below lines in your `printInstanceCreatedClassName` method.

```
StackTraceElement[] stackTraceElements = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()
```

`StackTraceElement` has methods various utility methods like `getClassName()`, `getFileName()`.

For Ex. to print the `caller` class, this would work:

```
System.out.println(stackTraceElements[stackTraceElements.length - 1].getClassName());
```

Comment: In this example it is ok. but action is fire from another side like mouse click or something this want help

Comment: Not sure where mouse click came from, but I'm sure we do have a stacktrace in every method.

Comment: In this question I post example code but in my application is swing client application.My requirement is to find object initiated class when mouse action performed Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace() it come form mouse event not form the main class

Comment: @janith1024 it doesn't matter where it came from, you'll always have a stacktrace, no?

Comment: This way, you would have no easy way of knowing from what class the actual instance was created from. Additionally, the instantiating class may not be in the stack at all. Wouldn't it be much more easier to just add the instantiating class name as a constructor parameter?

Comment: I edited the the code and add thread this time it not show the Test class in Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()

Comment: i''ve added relevant example. See the latest edit.

Comment: System.out.println(stackTraceElements[stackTraceElements.length - 1].getClassName()); gave out as 'Test$1' it means Thread class I created anonymously

Comment: Yes, you can do -2 instead of -1.

Comment: The question was went wrong direction because of edited person change content wrongly. I don't want the caller. thanks for your effort

Answer (score 3):

Just change the constructor to take an additional argument that specifies the calling class name. It's not that big of a change to the code structure if it's just one class you're concerned about. With an IDE like IntelliJ IDEA you can easily find all the constructor callers, go to them and edit them, assuming they're all in one code repository. Even if they're not, e.g. if plugins are in a separate repository and they're relevant, if you can write to that repository you can still do it as a separate step.

However, I should add that I'm not convinced that knowing the creating class is really the right way to solve your ultimate problem. What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: Thanks for answer. I know that. But may application is very old and very large, it is hard to change all the class constructor once to achieve this goal

Comment: @janith1024 never the less it is your only option. To change the behaviour and store this information, you have to add code (and a field) You could add this to a parent class.

Comment: @PeterLawrey My actual goal: object is pass as parameter to other methods and want to know where the object is initialize. I got idea to do this with out change constructor by looking all the answers, now I trying that and if It success. I'll post it as answer. Thanks for all helps

Answer (score -1):

I don't know about finding, but if you use toString() in the Test class, e.g.

```
String toString(){
    return "Test";
    //Test is the class name
}
```

and inherit Test class by making Sub the subclass then print the Test instance, then it will give you the name in the subclass.